# Music Liked System not updating

Tags: php, pdo

Guys, I have been working on my music like system for a while where it updated the system after a person, click the button, but on my side its not updating inside the database. But here go my code.

```
 <?php 
 DEFINE("IN_MUSICZOOM", 1);
 // MusicPlus Page System - Index
require_once('inc/config.php');

$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
$songID = isset($_GET['songID']) ? $_GET['songID'] : '';
$artistID = isset($_GET['artistID']) ? $_GET['artistID'] : '';
$action = $_GET['action'];
$songID = $_GET['songID'];

// Load Music
$loadSongs = $db->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM songs WHERE songID = ?', array($songID));                                    
if($loadSongs) {
 foreach($loadSongs as $loadSong) {
     $songID = $loadSong['songID'];
     $slug = $loadSong['slug'];
     $songName = $loadSong['songName'];
     $songViews = $loadSong['songViews'];
     $genres = $loadSong['genres'];
     $songDescription = $loadSong['songDescription'];
     $songLikes = $loadSong['songLikes'];
     $imgURL = $loadSong['imgURL'];
     $songURL = $loadSong['songURL'];
     $artistName = $loadSong['artistName'];
     $artistID = $loadSong['artistID'];
  }
}   

$pageName = "".$artistName." - ".$songName."";

require_once('inc/header.php');
if($action == "songliked") {
    if(!empty($songID)) {
        $db->update('UPDATE `songs` SET songLikes = songLikes + 1 WHERE songID = ?', array($songID));
        header('Location: index.php?action=liked'); 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Change this line `$pageName = "".$artistName." - ".$songName."";` to  $pageName = "$artistName - $songName";. Within double quotation marks, PHP replaces variables with their value.

Comment: Hello, I fix the issue guys i figure out if i remove  if(!empty($songID)) { it worked after you click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue when i change my coded from

```
if($action == "songliked") {
    if(!empty($songID)) {
        $db->update('UPDATE `songs` SET songLikes = songLikes + 1 WHERE songID = ?', array($songID));
        header('Location: index.php?action=liked'); 
    }
```

To this it worked after you push a button

```
if($action == "songliked") {
        $db->update('UPDATE `songs` SET songLikes = songLikes + 1 WHERE songID = ?', array($songID));
        header('Location: index.php?action=liked'); 
    }
```